# SQLite rawQuery() not updating elements correctly

Tags: android, sqlite

On Android I'm using `rawQuery()` to run this query against one of my tables:

```
UPDATE Icons SET position = position - 1 WHERE position <= 4 AND position > 1
```

When I look at the database afterwards in ADB the result I see looks like this, where the second column is the position column:

```
0|0
1|4
2|2
3|3
4|4
5|5
6|6
7|7
8|8
9|9
10|10
11|11
12|12
13|13
14|14
```

When I run the same query in ADB, all the rows are correctly updated instead of just one

```
0|0
1|3
2|1
3|2
4|3
5|5
6|6
7|7
8|8
9|9
10|10
11|11
12|12
13|13
14|14
```

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: There must be something more going on. Is there any more information that you can provide?

Comment: The project I'm working on is [here](https://github.com/lkorth/DraggableGridView). The query is run in `onRearrange()` in DraggableGridViewSampleActivity

Comment: I must have been affected by too many hours of work last night, dbaur is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rawQuery doesn't support updates, use execSQL instead